# Rhino get value from Scriptable including prototype chain

Tags: javascript, prototype, rhino

I am using Java Rhino and i have a `Scriptable` or `ScriptableObject`.

From this object i want to retrieve a value, but the value is not directly in this object but instead it is somewhere in the object's prototype chain.

So basically i want to do `object.get("key", object)` in the java code, but return the value from the prototype chain, if it does not exist in this object.

The docs of this get method states:

> Note that this method is not expected to traverse the prototype chain.

But unfortunately it does not say which method does this ...

I could write my own code to:

- check the object
- if not found: go to its prototype
- repeat this until a value was found or there is no prototype anymore

But i was wondering ... should't there be a method like this in Rhino already?

Where is this method?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i implemented the function myself. It looks like this now:

```
private Object getRecursive(Scriptable context, String name, Scriptable rootScope) {
    Object result;
    do {
        result = context.get(name, rootScope);
        context = context.getPrototype();
    } while (result == UniqueTag.NOT_FOUND && context != null);
    // continue as long as the result is NOT_FOUND and there is another parent prototype
    return result;
}
```

It loops through the given `context` object and its parent `prototypes` until it either finds the requested value or there is no more parent prototype.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
objArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(scriptableObject.prototype);
for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
if(objArray[i] == "whateverProperty")
log(i + " " + scriptableObject.prototype[i]);
}
```

This is how I always inspect an object's prototype.

Comment: I was asking about `Java`-code. This looks like `JavaScript`. But in case this is Java after all, it has several mistakes in it...